# Add a column if it doesn't exist in mysql, need a little help debugging

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that I want to use to check whether if a column exists and then insert it if it doesn't.

```
  $new_field ="IF NOT EXISTS 
               (SELECT * 
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                WHERE 
                    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dashboard'
                AND TABLE_NAME = '".$this->table_name."'
                AND COLUMN_NAME = 'timestamp')
                BEGIN
                ALTER TABLE `".$this->table_name."` 
                ADD mytimestamp DATETIME NOT NULL AFTER day_chan3";
```

I am not sure where my mistake is as I am not that good at sql queries and I would really aprpeciate the help. I know this looks very n00b and i am one.

I made the changes mentioned in the comment and I echoed the output of my query,

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dashboard' 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'admin_tmp' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'timestamp') 
BEGIN ALTER TABLE `admin_tmp` ADD mytimestamp DATETIME NOT NULL AFTER day_chan3
```

Comment: The fact that you are attempting to do this programmatically indicates that there may be larger problems afoot, such as a poorly designed database.  Not sure about mysql, but with at least one other database, if the table has records, you need a default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement is mixing up backticks with single quotes.  Use backticks only when necessary and only for identifiers (column names and table names).  Use single quotes only for string and date constant values.  So, try this:

```
         (SELECT * 
          FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
          WHERE 
              TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dashboard'
-----------------------------^ --------^
          AND TABLE_NAME = '".$this->table_name."'
---------------------------^ --------------------^
          AND COLUMN_NAME = 'timestamp')
----------------------------^ --------^
```

Comment: I made the changes but i still get an error, i echoed the output, can you please check and tell me what I did wrong ?

Comment: (1) Your syntax for the `if` is wrong (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html).  (2) `if` only works inside code blocks, such as stored procedures.